# how to turn an array into a callable function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `np.piecewise` function I would like to turn into a callable.

For example, suppose we have:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,10,1001)
my_func = np.piecewise(x, [x<8, x>=8], [np.sin, np.cos])
```

I am interested in making a function `my_callable_func` which has some reasonable evaluation of my_func. By reasonable, either we just default to the previous step in `x`, or we use some kind of linear approximation between successive `x` values.

For example, in this case `x = [0, 0.01, 0.02, ...]`, so given `my_new_func(0.015)`, I'd like that to return `np.sin(0.01)` or something like that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply wrap the `np.piecewise` call inside a  function definition,

```
In [1]: def my_callable_func(x):
   ...:     return np.piecewise(x, [x<8, x>=8], [np.sin, np.cos])
   ...: my_callable_func(0.015)

Out[1]: array(0.01499943750632809)
```

The value of your original `x` vector does not matter. This produces a 0D numpy array, but if necessary you can cast it to float, with `return float(...)`.